# Want to climb highest mountains of most European country's, how and where to start?

Tags: hiking, mountaineering

As I am always looking for my next challenge I have decided that I want to reach the highest points in some of the European countries.

I am a pretty fit person and I went on some 3-4 day trips in the mountains of Italy and Austria.

I want to start in 2018 with this challenge, but what countries should I do first and where do I find the right information? I am having trouble of finding information of mountains like Olympus and Großglockner.

As I want to start as soon as possible with this in 2018, what mountains should I do first and what time of year can I start?
Probably the mountains with the least snow first?

Some of the mountains I want to climb (not all in 2018 and not complete at all):

- Olympus (Greece)
- Zugspitze (Germany)
- El Teide (Spain)
- Großglockner (Austria)
- Dufourspitze (Swiss)
- Mont Blanc (France)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the great outdoors. I appreciate your enthusiasm about doing something like this, but it is going to be very difficult to answer your question merely based on *"I am a pretty fit person and I went on some 3-4 day trips in the mountains of Italy and Austria."* Rest assured, listing out easy treks in Europe isn't an difficult task, but to let anyone decide on which mountain to climb, it is a tough task. You know yourself better.

Comment: This is too broad (every single peak could have it's separate question about best season to climb) and it lacks any sign of research done. Please use google and read into description and tons of "experience reports" online - we live in a time where everything is documented online, so no shortage there. After that I am sure you will still have concrete question, which the community here at TGO will do its best to answer.

Comment: Hi Imsodin, i think ive formulated my question wrong. I dont want a detailed answer about every mountain. I just dont know where to start. Those mountains are the scope of what i want to achieve. But dont know at what do i have to look when planning my first one (best climate to begin, best season and dosnt have to be 1 of the list) so i can start my search and train more spefic for the first one and achieve my goals

Comment: Climbing the highest mountains in Europe is serious mountaineering. If all you've done is 3-4 day trips, you *will* die trying to climb e.g. Mont Blanc.

Answer (score 2):

I have always felt uncomfortable when it is about asking people do go for a particular trek, and sometimes the asking them otherwise.

> "I am a pretty fit person and I went on some 3-4 day trips in the mountains of Italy and Austria."

This doesn't ensure that you are ready do deal with treks/mountains in the region which may (or may not) be new to you. I am from India and I have been into mountaineering for over a decade now, but that doesn't directly qualify me to trek or plan a climb in Europe or even somewhere in Asia. Because, surroundings change, the way people go about it (might) change.

I don't want to be rude outright, and I'd never advice you to not to go for it, but I'd strongly recommend you to explore the region which you know about. (If you are not already) Be a regular hiker/trekker and get familiar with do's and dont's when things go wrong. A bad day (not a worst one!) in mountains shape you as a better trekker than 10 good days in mountains.

Now, if you are really ready to go with it, I'll help you with first item in your list. I am sure you can do this for other mountains by yourself.

---

### Olympus (Greece)

This mountain is in [Olympus National Park](http://www.olympusfd.gr/us/infos.asp).

- [This is the link to the details about the mountain route documented by the Olympus National Park authorities](http://www.olympusfd.gr/us/Diadromes.asp)
- [This is the link to the important phone numbers](http://www.olympusfd.gr/us/phones.asp). Try some of them and may be you will find someone who can guide you about the best season to visit.
- [This is the link to the general regulations to be observed](http://www.olympusfd.gr/us/Rules.asp)

---

Comment: Thanks for the info! The height isnt my problem and my fitness, its more the surroundings like snow etc. I dont know how to prepare for all that. Thats why ive put mount olympus first and el teide before Großglockner, because they are in warmer enviroments so maybe less hard and less unexpected obstacles? Or am i totally wro g about this?

Comment: @cger: Like I said, nobody would know the answer better than you do my friend. And, thats what one of our friends imsodin said above. This question is way too broad to answer, unless you don't address your skills in snow, rock or even mixed terrains for that matter.